# Emberjs dynamic inject from mixin

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a lot of controllers using difference services,where I should extend one mixin. In mixin, based on the controller's call I should inject difference service. Is it really do ? If yes, I open to any suggestions.
***My controller look like this:***

```
import FilterController from 'core/addon/filter/filter-controller';
import defaultMixin from 'default-mixin';

export default FilterController.extend(defaultMixin,{
  filter: Ember.inject.service(Pathes.inject.service.leaseFilter),
})
```

***Mixin:***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Views from '../const/views';
import ViewsService from '../static-services/views';

const {
  computed,
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Mixin.create({

  //THIS VIEW SERVICE I SHOULD INJECT BASED ON CONTROLLER
  //VIEW.INJECT.SERVICE.[LEASE,LEASE1,LEASE2,LEASE3]

  viewService: Ember.inject.service(Views.inject.service.Lease),

  defaultViewType: computed(
    'viewService.filteredViewsList',
    function () {
      const viewList = this.get('viewService.filteredViewsList');
      return ViewsService.getDefaultViewFromList(viewList);
    }
  ),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward option is to override the `viewService` in the controller's `extend`.

```
export default FilterController.extend(defaultMixin,{
  viewService: Ember.inject.service('someViewService'),
  filter: Ember.inject.service(Pathes.inject.service.leaseFilter),
})
```

That way, when you use it in the mixin code, any call to `this.get('viewService')` will resolve to whatever you have overridden in the `ctrl`.